# incrementing the last digit of a string using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

how to increment the last digit of a string using regular expression, ie `44test1222` to `44test1223`

i have incremented but how to change that. my regular expression in JavaScript code is as given below

```
var email='44test1222';
var number = email.match(/\d+$/);
number++;
```

Comment: use `/\d$/` not `/\d+$/`

Comment: `.match()` returns an array, not a single value.

Comment: @jfriend00 so instead of match what should i use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a replacement function. The function is called with matched string, and the return value of the function is used as replacement string.

```
var email='44test1222';
email.replace(/\d+$/, function(m) { return parseInt(m) + 1; })
// => "44test1223"
```

**NOTE**

Above code increments the last number, not the last digit. If you want to increment the last digit, you need to use `/\d$/` as a pattern, and may need to consider what should be done for digit 9.

Comment: Note for clarification, this actually increments ALL 4 last digits by one, not just the last.

Comment: @remus, Thank you for comment. I updated the answer to include it.